# List of spirits/drinks in Bastion

Tags: bastion

Can anyone provide a list of the spirits usable in the distillery in Bastion, as well as the Narrator's flavor text for each one?

For example:

- **Leechade** - "Leechade's so sour, it’ll perk you right up when you’re feeling low."

I'm looking to have a Bastion-themed drinking party with friends, and would like a handy list of the drinks with their descriptions in order to be able to plan for ingredients!  *[Inspiration](http://www.gourmetgaming.co.uk/post/14926530595/bastion-leechade-bastion-was-the-impressive-and)*

Comment: Awesome idea! I'm going to have to do this now.

Comment: Many thanks for the excellent idea !  That's a perfect geeky-party-theme :)  I love it (however, your 'inspiration' link hereabove looks dead).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Dreadrum - "Dreadrum's brewed from Swampweeds, so its effect is as bold as its flavor."
- Fetching Fizz - "Fetching Fizz is like a mouthful of nails, but the benefits are worth it."
- Werewhiskey - "Werewhisky has no scent but tastes like a peppered bootheel. It's not for everyone."
- Falling Malt - "Falling Malt is filled with crunchy minerals that'll keep you safe out on them rocks."
- Lunkhead Liqueur - "A sip of Lunkhead Liqueur will toughen you right up. Too bad it's like drinking a saddlebag."
- Mender Mead - "Folks say Mender Mead's good for you. It's like an herb garden in full bloom."
- Cinderbrick Stout - "Cinderbrick Stout sure goes down smooth. Then stays in your gut like a rock."
- Whale Ale - "Now Whale Ale ain't made from real whale. But it'll make you strong like one."
- Graver Gimlet - "Graver Gimlet tastes different the longer you swish it around. Miraculous stuff."
- Leechade - "Leechade's so sour, it'll perk you right up when you're feeling low."
- Doomshine - "Doomshine's a bit of an acquired taste, like a mouth full of horseradish"
- Cham-Pain - "Cham-Pain's made with Scumbag extract, hence the barley aroma, and the nausea"
- Squirt Cider - "Squirt Cider will toughen you right up. Too bad about the musty aftertaste."
- Hearty Punch - "Hearty Punch is so zesty it'll let you carry on even through the worst of times."
- Bastion Bourbon - "If you're feeling low, count on the buttery flavor of our own Bastion Bourbon."
- Black Rye - "Black Rye's like hot vineapple chowder on a cold day. Brings back memories."
- Bull Brandy - "Bull Brandy's thicker than paint. Makes your skin feel as tough as knifebark."
- Stabsinthe - "Stabsinthe's like drinkin' a cool breeze. Just don't go spittin' needles everywhere."
- Lifewine - "Lifewine's so rich, they say it's brought men back from the brink for one last taste."

There's also `Hop-Scotch`, but it's not available in the distillery, and doesn't have a line.

Comment: Wups. Guess I took too long pulling everything from the wiki -.-

Comment: Oh snap, a Bastion wiki!  For posterity, here's that link: http://bastion.wikia.com/wiki/Spirits

Answer (score 8):

Sure. Here's a list of all the Narrator lines about the spirits, right from the subtitles.

- **Squirt Cider** will toughen you right up. Too bad about the musty aftertaste.
- **Dreadrum**'s brewed from Swampweeds, so its effect is as bold as its flavor.
- **Fetching Fizz** is like a mouthful of nails, but the benefits are worth it.
- **Hop-Scotch** is light as sea foam, but you'll feel it in your legs right away.
- **Hearty Punch** is so zesty it'll let you carry on even through the worst of times.
- **Falling Malt** is filled with crunchy minerals that'll keep you safe out on them rocks.
- A sip of **Lunkhead Liqueur** will toughen you up. Too bad it's like drinking a saddlebag.
- **Bull Brandy**'s thicker than paint. Makes your skin feel tough as knifebark.
- If you're feeling low, count on the buttery flavor of our own **Bastion Bourbon**.
- **Doomshine**'s a bit of an acquired taste. Like a mouthful of horseradish.
- **Black Rye**'s like hot vineapple chowder on a cold day. Brings back memories.
- **Cinderbrick Stout** sure goes down smooth. Then stays in your gut like a rock.
- **Cham-Pain**'s made with Scumbag extract, hence the barley aroma, and the nausea.
- Now **Whale Ale** ain't made from real whale. But it'll make you strong like one.
- **Werewhiskey** has no scent but tastes like a peppered bootheel. It's not for everyone.
- Folks say **Mender Mead**'s good for you. It's like an herb garden in full bloom.
- **Leechade**'s so sour it'll perk you right up when you're feeling low.
- **Lifewine**'s so rich, they say it's brought men back from the brink for one last taste.
- **Graver Gimlet** tastes different the longer you swish it around. Miraculous stuff.
- **Stabsinthe** is like drinking a cool breeze. Just don't go spitting needles everywhere.

Hop-Scotch isn't actually available via the distillery, and I don't think I remember its associated line from the game, but I included it anyway for completeness' sake.